# cannot find module is the error if i try node hello.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying this command to run my js file to check whether node is installed properly or not: `C:\Users\vijay reddy\hello.js`

But I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\vijay reddy\hello.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
at startup (node.js:139:18)
at node.js:968:3
```

Comment: That means that there doesn't exist a file `hello.js` in that directory.

Comment: Isn't the error message pretty clear? It says node cannot find the file `hello.js`

Comment: I do have that file there. properly gave the path, how can i resolve this..

Comment: yes. i want to run that test file in order to check whether node is installed properly or not.

Comment: I am a beginner... why it is down voted..? its discouraging... but i edited my question again..is that now clear?

Comment: Then why the hell this guy in his blog directed like this [http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows]

Comment: Can you show the code you're actually trying to run? The error is well and good, but show us what you're doing to get the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you create a file `hello.js` like so:

`console.log('Hello World!');`

And you are in the directory it exists in, and run (from your command prompt):

`node hello.js`

You will get the correct output if node is installed correctly.

To figure out why it's not, try the other commands they suggest.  If you try:

`node -v`

and you get nothing, or an error, then that means either Node isn't installed, or it's not in your current users %PATH%.

Also, depending on how you created hello.js, Windows may have "helpfully" changed it to hello.js.txt for you.

Comment: node -v i tried and got v4.4.7 also tried npm -v and got 2.15.8

Comment: So then node is working.  If you're in the directory that hello.js is located and you type `node hello.js` you'll get the output I quoted.

Comment: iam in that directory only and if i run 'node hello.js' it showing the above error.. that is why i raised this question here.. pls help

Comment: But you still haven't shown us the actual command you tried to run, nor the contents of your code like I asked. I can't guess my way to an answer for you. That's likely why someone down voted you.

Comment: oh ok..'C:\Users\vijay reddy\Desktop>node hello.js' this is the exact code i tried to run.. Iam following step by step procedure mentioned in this tutorial.. iam at last step i.e.,**create atest file and run it** mentioned in this link[http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows]

Comment: Run dir from the command line please and post the results. And the contents of hello.js

Comment: IF i run dir command it is showing **12-07-2016  22:35                34 hello .js**

Comment: which means hello.js file exists in that directory

Comment: Looks like there's a space between the o and the .js, is that a copy error or is it like that on your system?

Comment: i tried both ways including with space and without space after hello i.e., hello .js and hello.js.. in my system i saved the file name as hello .js.

Comment: Save the file without the space please and then run 'node hello.js' without a space

Comment: So to be clear, hello.js was NOT on your file system, hello .js was.  ;)

Comment: yeah its so silly for me.. i should have seen it .. thanks for you help man

Comment: then even why that hello .js didnt run??

Comment: Because the space has to be quoted or escaped. Easier to just not have spaces.

Answer (score 0):

May be my answer is not exactly relevant for this.But if you work on Windows OS and learning by  creating manual files, another reason can be that windows saves files with the extension .txt. That means, if you create a file with mouse click-> create empty document and save as yourFileName.js, The OS saves as yourFileName.js.txt. So better to go the file's directory in command line and type dir and list down files. It will show all files clearly.

Answer (score 0):

module error for hello.js was occured due to filelname mismatch error.

Please check file name on both command & directory by running dir command in application directory.

```
dir
```

Common filename error was hello.js is saved as hello.js.txt because extensions are hidden by default in some OS. Make sure that preview extension was enabled in OS file manager.

Answer (score -2):

> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\vijay reddy\hello.js'

You wrote it was saved to the desktop, then this line should look like this

> C:\Users\vijay reddy\Desktop>node hello.js

This most likely have something to do with you user inheritance level for your login to computer itself. It's stating you another path, try to save in `Vijay reddy` directly or make a guest name, that should always start in `Document` when using the `cmd`.

Comment: Try to write full answers and if you don't know, please research or skip such problems.